# Why RDS PostgreSQL `MaximumUsedTransactionIDs` not decreasing even after data base seems correctly `VACUUM FREEZE`'d?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

My `MaximumUsedTransactionIDs` seems to keep growing indefinitely, but I have
these evidences hinting me it *maybe* should not be happening that way:

```
$ PGPASSWORD=$MY_USER_LAND_RDS_SUPER_USER_PASSWORD psql -h $MY_RDS_INSTANCE -d
my_main_data_base -U $MY_USER_LAND_RDS_SUPER_USER
psql (9.5.8, server 9.5.10)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 
256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

my_main_data_base=> SELECT datname FROM pg_database;
     datname
-------------------
 template0
 rdsadmin
 template1
 postgres
 my_main_data_base
 another_data_base
(6 rows)

my_main_data_base=> VACUUM FREEZE; SELECT relname, age(relfrozenxid) AS xid_ag
e FROM pg_class JOIN pg_stat_all_tables USING (relname) ORDER BY xid_age DESC 
LIMIT 5;
VACUUM
       relname        | xid_age
----------------------+---------
 pg_toast_1150794     |   63707
 a_user_table         |   63707
 another_user_table   |   63707
 pg_toast_1223948     |   63707
 pg_toast_1223998     |   63707
(5 rows)

my_main_data_base=> \q
$ PGPASSWORD=$MY_USER_LAND_RDS_SUPER_USER_PASSWORD psql -h $MY_RDS_INSTANCE -d
another_data_base -U $MY_USER_LAND_RDS_SUPER_USER
psql (9.5.8, server 9.5.10)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 
256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

another_data_base=> VACUUM FREEZE; SELECT relname, age(relfrozenxid) AS xid_ag
e FROM pg_class JOIN pg_stat_all_tables USING (relname) ORDER BY xid_age DESC 
LIMIT 5;
VACUUM
      relname       | xid_age
--------------------+---------
 pg_toast_2964      |   12350
 pg_toast_3592      |   12350
 pg_toast_2396      |   12350
 pg_db_role_setting |   12350
 pg_authid          |   12350
(5 rows)

another_data_base=> \q
$ _
```

`$MY_USER_LAND_RDS_SUPER_USER` is what AWS RDS provides me as a *superuser*.
It is a super user from the RDS point of view, but it is **not** a superuser
from the PostgreSQL point of view.

---

I would expect now to have `MaximumUsedTransactionIDs` decreased, but it does
not. It is still at about `~80.000.000`.

I have planned that after it reaches `100.000.000` I'll fork a development
version of the RDS instance where I'll make it so AWS boots the `autovacuum`
process at it.

### Questions

1. What is happening with `MaximumUsedTransactionIDs`? Why it does not shrink?
2. Will `autovacuum` take care of `MaximumUsedTransactionIDs` once booted?
3. Is `autovacuum` irrelevant in my scenario because I run manually unqualified
   `VACUUM FREEZE`s from time to time on all my user land databases?
4. Should I just ignore `MaximumUsedTransactionIDs`?
5. Can I somehow connect to database `rdsadmin` to `SELECT` `age(relfrozenxid)`
   there?

**EDIT**, fulfilling your first request, adding...

```
$ PGPASSWORD=$MY_USER_LAND_RDS_SUPER_USER_PASSWORD psql -h $MY_RDS_INSTANCE -d
my_main_data_base -U $MY_USER_LAND_RDS_SUPER_USER
psql (9.6.6, server 9.5.10)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 
256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

postgresql=> SELECT datname, datfrozenxid FROM pg_database;
     datname       | datfrozenxid
-------------------+--------------
 template0         |         1822
 rdsadmin          |         1822
 template1         |         1822
 postgres          |         1822
 my_main_data_base |     76628948
 another_data_base |     76681257
(6 rows)

postgresql=> \q
$ _
```

Comment: Do you see which database of yours is aging?  Run `SELECT datname, datfrozenxid FROM pg_database;` so check.

Comment: so = to above.  And the smaller the datfrozenxid, the older it is.

Comment: Cool... I suppose `autovacuum` will fix the situation by freezing the templates and `postgres` and `rdsadmin`..?

Comment: I am not so sure about `template0`, as one cannot just connect to it.  But `autovacuum` should be turned on in any case, and in normal cases it should take care of this.

Comment: I expect that to reach `100.000.000` transactions in two to ten months and then I'll follow this up eventually.

Comment: I think 100,000,000 is a bit too early. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implement-an-early-warning-system-for-transaction-id-wraparound-in-amazon-rds-for-postgresql/

Comment: I've no idea how widely `autovacuum` runs at that system, even if it ever runs (I never changed any AWS default configuration kv pair actually). If I remember correctly `100.000.000` is the age a PostgreSQL system (or table..?) has to reach before `autovacuum` will attempt to freeze transaction IDs (`autovacuum_freeze_max_age`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activate autovacuum in the parameter group and when it hits the configured level (min 100.000.000) it'll start and `MaximumUsedTransactionIDs` will go down drastically.